# Binding a DataGridView to a lazy LINQ query on a Dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.0, datagridview, bindingsource

EDIT: I'm noticing that this happens specifically when I bind to a Dictionary, which is something I missed in my original post; I've updated the post.

If I set my BindingSource's datasource to a late evaluating LINQ query that draws from a Dictionary, it seems to work fine except for one thing: when the result is empty. When the query returns nothing, the DataGridView ends up getting bound to the empty KeyCollection or ValueCollection itself, as if it were a data item. This causes a blank row to appear in the DataGridView.

It seems like BindingSource is built to recognize that an empty List is a datasource with zero items, but does not recognize that an empty KeyCollection or ValueCollection is a datasource with zero items, and instead thinks it is a datasource with one item (the empty collection).

Would this have something to do with the interfaces that Dictionary does (or does not) implement?

ex:

```
...
private readonly Dictionary<Record> mRecords = new Dictionary<Record>();
...

private IEnumerable<Record> GetDataSource()
{
   return mRecords.Values.OrderBy(x => x.Amount);
}

...
mBindingSource.DataSource = GetDataSource();
...
```

I can of course get around this by using ToList(), but then I lose the lazy evaluation.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Interesting behavior.  I haven't independently verified it, but here's an idea - if you don't mind seeing a blank row in the case of an empty collection, what about using `.DefaultIfEmpty()`?

Comment: That is similar to using ToList() where you are no longer using lazy evaluation. The datasource would be set to null, and I would need to call the method again to get any results to show later.